# Swift - Sorting one to many

Tags: ios, core-data, swift3

I have two entities:

SwimmingPool 
Parameter

swimmingPool has a relationship to parameter (each pool can have multiple param so a one-to-many relation).

In my main view controller i'm fetching data for the pools.
now i'm passing through a segue the data to a second view controller which holds a list of all the actions tied to the specific pool.
From here i'm sending the data to a 3rd view controller which has a list of all the parameters tied to the pool.

I'm able to get the data and display them but it seems i cannot sort them.

here's the code to fetch the pool in my main VC:

```
func attemptFetch() {

    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<SwimminPool> = SwimminPool.fetchRequest()
    let dataSort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "poolCreatedAt", ascending: false)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [dataSort]


     let controller = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)

    controller.delegate = self
    self.controller = controller

    do {
        try controller.performFetch()
    } catch {
        let error = error as NSError
        print("\(error.debugDescription)")
    }

}
```

the segue to pass data:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
     if segue.identifier == "MyParams" {
        if let destination = segue.destination as? MyParamsVC {
            destination.swimmingPool = swimmingPoolHome
        }
    }
}
```

here's the code to configure the cell in the third controller:

```
var swimmingPool: SwimmingPool! // data received from the segue

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ParamCell", for: indexPath) as! ParamCell
    configureCell(cell: cell, indexPath: indexPath as NSIndexPath)
    return cell
}
 func configureCell(cell: ParamCell, indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let param = swimmingPool.parameters?.allObjects[indexPath.row]
    cell.configureCell(parameter: param as! Parameter)
}
```

and finally my paramCell:

```
lass ParamCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var paramCreatedAt: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var noteLbl: UILabel!

func configureCell(parameter: Parameter) {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "dd-MMMM-yyyy, HH:mm:ss"
    let dateString = formatter.string(from: parameter.createdAt!).capitalized
    paramCreatedAt.text = dateString
    noteLbl.text = parameter.paramNotes
}
```

}

Any Idea on how to sort data with the date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `MyParamsVC` create an separate data source array:

```
var parameters = [Parameter]()
```

Add the `didSet` observer to `swimmingPool` which gets the `Parameter` instances and sorts it (change `createdAt` to your desired property)

```
var swimmingPool: SwimmingPool!  { // data received from the segue
    didSet {
        parameters = (swimmingPool.parameters?.allObjects as! [Parameter]).sorted(by: {$0.createdAt! < $1.createdAt!})
    }
}
```

Replace `cellForRowAt` and `configureCell` with ( I changed `NSIndexPath` to Swift 3 `IndexPath`)

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ParamCell", for: indexPath) as! ParamCell
    configureCell(cell: cell, indexPath: indexPath)
    return cell
}

func configureCell(cell: ParamCell, indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let param = parameters[indexPath.row]
    cell.configureCell(parameter: param)
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer... as always you are super kind.... i've done everything you suggested... but i get the error "Index out of range
" my fetch request is in my main VC so in my params VC i have no fetch request and the func controllerWillChangeContent and controllerDidChangeContent are not called.... is it possibile that this is the problem?

Comment: i actually have also an error of unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value on the dateString...

Comment: You don't need to fetch data in `MyParamsVC`. Just pass the `swimmingPool` instance in the segue and assign it to the `swimmingPool` property. You don't need a fetchedresultscontroller either.

Comment: What do you return in `numberOfRows`? You have to return `parameters.count`

Comment: swimminPool.parameters?.count i'll try to return just parameters.count

Comment: it works... funny thing.... if i click and go to details... row 1 has the value of row 3, row 2 has the value of row 1 and row 3 has the value of row 2...https://prnt.sc/fuv7ud i'm definitely missing something.... this things does not happens if i don not order the values...

Comment: On what are you sorting? On date strings?. You can't do that reliably. You have to convert `String` to `Date`

Comment: i'm converting on createdAt which is saved like so: parameter.createdAt = Date() during the creation of the parameter

Comment: Are there other places where you use `swimmingPool.parameters?...` in the detail controller. Replace all occurrences with (the sorted) `parameters...`

Comment: forget to change it in didSelectRowAt... now it works... but if i try to delete a row... it gives me the found nil error...  here's the code.. let parameter = self.parameters[indexPath.row]
            context.delete(parameter)
            
            do {
                try context.save()........

Comment: It depends if you want to remove the parameter from the relationship or remove the parameter from the entity. For the table you have to remove the item also from the data source (`parameters.remove(at: indexPath.row)`

Comment: (parameters.remove(at: indexPath.row) needs to go in editActionsForRowAt or in the controller switch?

Comment: i have a cascade relation with the swimming pool so if i remove the parameter i just would like to remove it from the entity so not to display it anymore in that swimming pool..

Comment: In any case you have to make sure to keep Core Data and the table view data source in sync.

Comment: did it.... it works perfectly.... Vadian i don't know how to thank you!!!! you helped me a lot during this project!! you have been so kind!!! now i will have to understand why it does not update the table when i save the parameter.... but with this you saved me... i was loosing hope! :) many many thx!!